# Converting txt file to CSV and splitting data into columns

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have been stuck for the last 3 hours figuring out how to split string in R. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx9s7.png)
I have been using the str_split function to split the string by using delimiter : and separate into 2 rows.
Unfortunately I keep getting this error and I don't know how to sort it.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Also, please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Do you mean ```tidyr::separate(df, col = Data, into = c("name", "email"), sep = ":")``` ?